# Como usar API do Last.fm?

Tags: ios, web-service, api, swift

Preciso fazer uma aplicação para iOS que trabalha com a [API do Last.fm](http://www.lastfm.com.br/api/intro) e tudo começa fazendo uma [requisição para autenticar o usuário](http://www.lastfm.com.br/api/show/auth.getMobileSession).

Minha dúvida é: de que forma faço isso com **Swift**. Eu sou iniciante, então não entendi bem como fazer essa requisição com **POST** e **HTTPS** que eles dizem.
A API inteira é baseada nisso, então se eu ver um exemplo dessa, consigo fazer todo resto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ismael, o que você precisa basicamente é realizar requisições para a *API* que podem ser feitas facilmente utilizando `NSURL`, `NSURLRequest` e `NSURLSession`. Estes três são preferencialmente a partir do **iOS 7**, caso contrário existe também o `NSURLConnection`.

Seguindo um exemplo de [requisição REST da API](http://www.lastfm.com.br/api/rest), você inicia a sessão e define a **URL** que será feita a requisição:

```
var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getSimilar&format=json")!)
```

Note que eu utilizei `format=json` para o retorno, pois é mais fácil de manipular o resultado em **JSON** do que em **XML**, mas você pode remover este parâmetro se preferir.

Agora, como indica a **API**, você deve utilizar **POST**, então você define os 4 parâmetros obrigatórios (*claro, substitua XXX pelos reais valores*) para a requisição e o método:

```
var params = "api_key=XXX&api_sig=XXX&username=XXX&password=XXX".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!

request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = params.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
```

Feito isto, basta realizar a requisição e o seu retorno será em *JSON*, assim como definimos lá em cima, e a *string* `strData` você manipula da forma que for necessária:

```
var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    if error == nil {
        // sucesso
    } else {
        // falha
    }
})

task.resume()
```

Comment: Perfeita explicação, ficou bem claro. Agradeço pela ajuda!

Comment: Se tiver respondido sua pergunta, considere marcá-la como correta, assim irá ajudar outros com sua mesma necessidade ;)